# Algorithm for splitting date according to new record

Tags: mysql, algorithm, date, stored-procedures

In my mysql database 
I have to write stored procedure.
I have table DATE which has 4 Columns

Table: DATE

```
Sq number(auto generated)   From_Date       To_date     value
2                           20170112        20170115    3
3                           20170116        20170220    5
4                           20170221        20170301    7
```

and so on

so if I get data which has to be added to table
from and to as 20170119 and 20170201 and value 6

then my table should look like
Table:DATE

```
Sq number(auto generated)   From_Date       To_date     value
2                           20170112        20170115    3
3                           20170116        20170118    5
4                           20170221        20170301    7
5                           20170119        20170201    6
6                           20170202        20170220    5
```

is there any algorithm or any logic to implement this kind of situation and handle all other possibilities

Comment: You could use a `TRIGGER` to do this

Comment: what would the trigger contains?

Comment: You need to describe the algorithm you would like to use as a minimum. Also an attempt to implement it would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment...

If it was me, I'd revise the question, e.g.

```
start_val end_val
        3       5
        6      11
```

What would be the effect of bringing the values 4 and 8 into this table?